# Is the Hidden tag too specific and redundant?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I started looking at the Hidden tag when I answered this question: [Can I hide using Cunning Sneak with Wilderness Skirmisher?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/27230/can-i-hide-using-cunning-sneak-with-wilderness-skirmisher)

To me it seems that stealth (a much more widely used tag) would make more sense than having a hidden tag which is overly specific. Tagging a question with both 4e and stealth would include everything that the hidden tag connotes while also having a wider subject matter and both the stealth tag can be applied to non-4e questions whereas hidden cannot. Thoughts?

Comment: Synonym added...

Answer (score 4):

I've changed the tag on the question to [stealth](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stealth) and considering that the current use of [hidden](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hidden) is all 4e questions and in 4e hidden is a subset of stealth, I've proposed a tag synonym.

User with sufficient score in stealth can go [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags/stealth/synonyms) to vote on the synonym.